# How to get Unit of Work to function with Service Pattern?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I am using the Unit of Work pattern, as it is described in this [article](https://chsakell.com/2015/02/15/asp-net-mvc-solution-architecture-best-practices/). The article explains that every service should inject a UnitOfWork:

```
private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
```

Furthermore a service must have a public method to commit unit-of-work operations:

```
public void Save()
{
   _unitOfWork.Commit();
}
```

The Save method may only be invoked by the (webapi) controller which calls the service.

But here are my concerns:

1) The controller may call more than one service with database updates, and in which case it should call Save() for each service? What then if a rollback is needed?

Like:

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateArchive()
{
   _service1.DoUpdate();
   _service1.Save();
   _service2.DoUpdate();
   _service2.Save();
}
```

What if service2.Save fails?

2) what if a service calls another service, how will the controller know which Save to call?

I am a bit confused with this unit-of-work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> and in which case it should call Save() for each service

That depends on whether services share the same unit of work. If yes, call `Save` on any of them, it delegates the operation to the very same UoW.

> What then if a rollback is needed

Since there are no transactions, how are you supposed to roll anything back?

On the other hand, introducing an explicit transaction over the orchestration makes it trivial to rollback changes:

```
try
{
  using ( TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope() )
  {
     _service1.DoUpdate();
     _service1.Save();
     _service2.DoUpdate();
     _service2.Save();

     scope.Complete();
  }
}
catch
{
   // rollback occurs since the transaction was not completed
}
```

The `TransactionScope` is quite handy as it should correctly handle both a transaction on a shared UoW and a transaction over multiple different UoWs injected into different services.

> What if service2.Save fails?

You rollback the transaction, there is barely any other option here.

Anyway, [repositories/uow over EF are disputable](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/180851/why-shouldnt-i-use-the-repository-pattern-with-entity-framework/220126#220126). Part of your problem is that multiple services share the same instance of the UoW so basically it doesn't matter which `Save` you call, they all call `SaveChanges` on the very same `DbContext`.

My opinion (even though opinions should be avoided here) is that you could possibly drop `Save`s from your services and stick with the single `SaveChanges` on your db context at the end of the orchestration. This would make the intention clearer - services are to change the internal state of the UoW but the responsibility to persist changes is on the controller.

Comment: About your last paragraph: you wouldn't call SaveChanges on db context directly from the controller, would you? I mean, shouldn't it be abstracted away?

Comment: That would really depend on whether I'd have the DbContext at hand. If not (e.g. it's injected by a DI container and you don't even see it anywhere in the controller) I would call `Save` on one of services.